# JMF: Cannot set media time on an unrealized controller

Tags: java, jmf

I'm trying to use JMF to play a sound every time I hit a button.

This is what I have to contruct the media player:

```
MediaPlayer mp = new javax.media.bean.playerbean.MediaPlayer();
mp.setMediaLocation("file:///D:/fall.wav");
mp.setPlaybackLoop(false);
```

And, to play the sound once, I do

```
mp.start();
mp.setMediaTime(new Time(0));
mp.stop();
```

The first time I play the sound, i get a

```
javax.media.NotRealizedError: Cannot set media time on a unrealized controller
```

and an

```
Exception in thread AWT-EventQueue-0" javax.media.NotRealizedError: 
  Cannot set media time on a unrealized controller
```

on the setMediaTime line. This doesn't happen any subsequent time I hit the button that makes the sound, it only happens the first time. If i change the constructor and add

```
mp.realize();
```

at the end, then it doesn't throw those errors, but it also doesn't play the sound the first time.

How do I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 1):

`mp.start()` is asynchronous. So when you call `mp.setMediaTime(new Time(0));`
 immediately after calling `start()`, the player is not yet realized. 
  You could add a `ControllerListener` and listen to its events. Once you get the `RealizedEvent`, then set the media time. It will be a good idea to initially call `mp.realize()` and on getting the event, set the media time and then call `start()`